# guardar varias variables sin usar listas

Tags: python, python-3.x

nos piden entregar un código donde ingresemos una cantidad x de datos, luego ingresar x datos y realizar una especie de promedio inverso, ejemplo:

5 - 10,12,12,13,12.6

x_1/1 = 12 (1 numero entregado) ---> x_1 = 10

(x_1 + x_2)/2 = 12 (2 numero entregado) ---> x_1 = 10, x_2 =14

(x_1 + x_2 + x_3)/3 = 12 (3 numero entregado) ---> x_3 = 12

y asi, el problema es que el ejercicio esta pensado para resolverse sin usar listas,

personalmente solo logre realizar este codigo utilizando listas

```
    dias = int(input())
    
    valores = []
    resultado = []
    suma = 0
    for i in range(dias):
      x=float(input())
      valores.append(x) #guardamos x valores

resultado.append(valores[0])

for i in range(dias-1): 
  for j in range(i+1):
    suma += resultado[j] #contador 
  resultado.append(valores[i+1]*(i+2)-suma) #agregamos la multiplicación menos el contador
  suma=0

for i in range(dias):
  print(int(resultado[i]))
```

el problema que encontré fue que tengo que mostrar el resultado después de hacer todos los inputs, entonces seria encontrar la manera de almacenar variables sin necesidad de usar listar

Comment: entonces utiliza tuplas :D

Comment: cuales son los valores que toma `x_1`,`x_2`, etc??

Answer (score 0):

No tengo muy claro cuales son las operaciones matemáticas que necesitas realizar para ese 'promedio inverso', pero la lógica del programa sería basicamente la de calcular un promedio.

Aquí soluciona la fórmula `(x1 + x2 + x3 )/ 3` . Siguiendo estos pasos puedes añadir más operaciones.

```
n_veces = int(input('Número de datos:   '))
cont = suma = 0
while cont < n_veces:
    numero = float(input('Dame un número:   '))
    suma += numero

print(f'El resultado es {suma/n_veces :.2f}')
```

***Promedio inverso***

Si **calcular promedio** es:

`media = (suma_anterior + num) / cont`

La suma (suma anterior + nuevo número) / el número de números

Entiendo que el **promedio inverso** es:

`num = (nueva_media * cont) - suma_anterior`

Siendo la nueva_media el número que introduces por teclado

Supongo que devuelves por pantalla cada número calculado, así que solo necesitas guardar la suma de los números anteriores y un contador con el número de pasos que llevas.

El código podría ser:

```
n_datos = int(input('Número de datos:   '))
suma_anterior = 0
for n_veces in range(1, n_datos + 1):
    nueva_media = float(input('Dame la nueva media:   '))
    num = (nueva_media * n_veces) - suma_anterior
    print( f'{n_veces}a vez =>  Num = {num :.2f}\nMedia (número que me das) => {nueva_media}')
    suma_anterior += num
```

Comment: no recomiendo usar asignación múltiple pero dado que trabajas con datos inmutables no hay problema, pero si fuese con mutables podría haber confusión

Comment: la idea del promedio inverso es que el dato que nosotros ingresamos es justamente el promedio y los datos que bota el programa son los elementos que generan ese promedio

Comment: Gracias @FelipeMarín